# How to generate only-ocean coordinates and display them in a visual map in Java

Tags: java, coordinates, geotools

I am making a kind of tracking app which requires to generate coordinates for different ships and visualize their position in a map.

I have research for similares questions, but there are all about land-only coordinates. Also, I have seen so different frameworks like GeoTools or Unfolding but the documentation is so large I cannot find what I'm looking for.

I just need to generate coordinates at the ocean, and then display the label in a map.

In Python there's a library that checks is a point is on land or not (so you can check if it is on ocean or not), and then with Folium you can add marks with aditional information.

No idea if there is a similar approach with Java.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to know whether or not a longitudinal/latitudinal point is in the ocean? You want to track ships, doesn't the ship's coordinate on itself imply that it's a marine coordinate? However, I have apps where I need to draw data on the entirety of the oceans. To accomplish this, I use a grid of marine coordinates that are spaced 1 degree from one another. If a coordinate is between 4 of such points, it means it is in the ocean.

Comment: Yes. I'm creating "ships objects" and then I need to set random coordinates for each one.

Comment: Wait a moment. I uploaded the wrong file. I'll edit the link in a moment.

Comment: I messed up twice by generating arrays with the wrong coordinates. Now it is finally the correct, final one. https://filebin.net/5b0vxj3a0wvwdqtx/coordinates_ocean.json?t=ddwk4cc9

Comment: Everytime I try to download it it gives error nearly the end

Comment: That's annoying. The file has been uploaded to my own server: https://djinesse.com/public/coordinates_ocean.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download my grid of oceans-only coordinates:

https://djinesse.com/public/coordinates_ocean.json
The file may be deleted in the near future.

How to use it:

```
String fromFile = FileUtils.readFileToString( new File( "c:/users/you/downloads/coordinates.json" ), "UTF-8" );
JSONArray coordinates = new JSONArray( fromFile );
// pull random coordinates from the array:
int index = (int) (Math.random() * coordinates.length() );
JSONObject randomCoordinate = coordinates.getJSONObject( index );
double longitude = randomCoordinate.getDouble( "lo" );
double latitude = randomCoordinate.getDouble( "la" );
```

Required `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You should at least provide a link that will be valid for longer than a week. It would be even better if you explained the method you used to generate the file, preferably with some example code.

Comment: That method would be useless as it only works when applied to a personal date sheet I can't share.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it something like this:

1. Download a set of land polygons
2. Store them in a spatial index
3. Generate a random point and test if it falls on land
4. Continue generating until it doesn't fall on land
5. Repeat until you have enough points

   ```
   public class PointInSea {
    private static final FilterFactory2 FF = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
    private SimpleFeatureCollection features;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      URL url = new URL("https://datahub.io/core/geo-countries/r/countries.geojson");
      Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
      params.put(GeoJSONDataStoreFactory.URL_PARAM.key, url);
      DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
      PointInSea me = new PointInSea();
      me.setFeatures(ds.getFeatureSource(ds.getTypeNames()[0]).getFeatures());
      List<Point> ret = me.getPoints(10);
      for (Point p : ret) {
        System.out.println(p);
      }
    }

    private void setFeatures(SimpleFeatureCollection features2) throws IOException {
      features = new SpatialIndexFeatureCollection(features2);
    }

    private List<Point> getPoints(int i) {
      List<Point> ret = new ArrayList<>(i);
      for (int count = 0; count < i; count++) {
        Point p = createRandomPoint();

        Contains filter = FF.contains(FF.property(features.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName()), 
            FF.literal(p));
        while (features.subCollection(filter).size() != 0) {
          p = createRandomPoint();
          filter = FF.contains(FF.property(features.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName()), FF.literal(p));
        }
        ret.add(p);
      }
      return ret;
    }

    public static Point createRandomPoint() {
      double latitude = (Math.random() * 180.0) - 90.0;
      double longitude = (Math.random() * 360.0) - 180.0;
      GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
      Point point;
      if (CRS.getAxisOrder(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84) == CRS.AxisOrder.EAST_NORTH) {
        /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
        point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
      } else {
        point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(latitude, longitude));
      }
      return point;
    }

   }
   ```